# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop - date and time synchronization issue

Tags: ubuntu, time, timezone

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop a couple of days back. During installation, I chose the timezone to be my local time zone i.e., Kolkata, India (Indian Standard Time). However, after booting my system, the time and date are showing incorrect values.

**Displayed values:**

date: Sat Aug 10 2019
time: 22:16:xx

**Actual values at that time:**

date: Sat Aug 10 2019
time: 11:16:xx

Precisely, the displayed time is 11 hours ahead of the actual time.

[image: Wrong date and time displayed]

In Settings --> Date and Time, the Automatic Date and Time, and the Automatic Time Zones switches are also enabled.

[image]

I found some articles on the internet using which I tried to analyze/fix the issue (Screenshots attached).

1. Run `timedatectl`
   [image]
2. Installed `ntp`
   [image]
3. Run `sudo ntpq -p`
   [image]
4. Run `sudo nmap -p123 -sU -P0 localhost`. I think it checks the status of UDP port 123.
   [image]

What should be the next steps I need to perform to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix**: Answers provided by @pomsky at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164803/ubuntu-18-04-desktop-date-and-time-synchronization-issue).

> Looks like your BIOS clock is set to UTC+11:00 (as per RTC time in the
>   output of timedatectl). Ubuntu (Unix-like system in general) by
>   default considers the BIOS clock to be set at UTC time.
>
> Enter BIOS while booting and set your BIOS clock to UTC time (i.e. 5.5
>   hours behind your local time).